# Parsing JSON Issue

Tags: apex, api, json

So I've got a JSON that'll be coming in apex via an API in the format below:

```
            "articles": [ '+
'                     { '+
'                         "originalURL": "http://search.eci.gov.in/ae_2008e/", '+
'                         "dateCollected": "2008-12-11", '+
'                         "c6URL": "https://secure.c6-intelligence.com/c6images/0013960000/0013955977.pdf", '+
'                         "categories": [ '+
'                             { '+
'                                 "name": "PEP" '+
'                             } '+
'                         ], '+
'                         "snippet": { '+
'                             "title": "kjlkjl", '+
'                             "summary": "The source provides political exposure detai\"ls of t\"he subject. Please refer to the Political Positions and Linked Persons sections of the profile.", '+
'                             "keywordsMatched": [ '+
'                                 "jklj" '+
'                             ] '+
'                         } '+
'                     } '+
'                 ], '
```

The problem i am facing here is that some summary fields have values in which double quotes(") are used in the content and this causes the parser class/method to fail. Does anyone have an idea as to how to resolve this.PS: if i try and use replace all to replace ':' or '\"' with any other character all double quotes are replaced

Comment: shouldnt a parser be able to handle those escape characters? If its not a valid json I would ask to get a valid json.

Comment: How are you getting that JSON formatted value. That itself looks wrong. Double quotes inside values looks like a wrong JSON formatted value `detai\"ls`. Are you getting that from API or from UI?

Answer (score 1):

Do examine the incoming JSON carefully. A single `\` in front of an embedded `"` is the correct escaping in JSON.

But to represent a literal `\` in an Apex String, as in your code sample, you need a second escaping backslash.

So, for example, this parses and the assert passes:

```
String s = '{"a": "b\\"d"}';
Map<String, Object> m = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(s);
System.assertEquals(3, ((String)m.get('a')).length());
```

but this will not parse as `\"` has already mapped by the Apex compiler to `"` and so the JSON parser at runtime sees `"b"d"`:

```
String s = '{"a": "b\"d"}';
```